# How to spyOn method that returns Promise -Angular

Tags: angular, promise, spyon

The below method calls CheckLastEmployee method which returns true/false.

```
async nextEmployee(empId:number) {
    let isLast;
    await this.CheckLastEmployee(empId).then(x=>{isLast=x});
    if (isLast) {
        Submit();
    }
}
```

More logic inside CheckLastEmployee....copied a part of the code..

```
async CheckLastEmployee(empId:number){
    let enrollment = new Map<string, boolean>();
    await this.GetEnrolledPrograms().then(res => enrollment = res);
    if(empId==10)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

**Test case .spec.ts**

```
 it('Is Last Employee-submit',()=>{
        spyOn(component,'CheckLastEmployee').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
        spyOn(component,'Submit');
        component.nextEmployee(10);
        expect(component.Submit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }
```

the above test case fails.

Comment: If you're using Jest the try `spyOn(component,'CheckLastEmployee').mockResolvedValue(true)`. See https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue

Comment: i am using jasmine and karma...any solution with jasmine?

Comment: I can't see that you call `nextEmployee()` in your test

Comment: that was a typo...I have called. Edited the question now

Comment: `CheckLastEmployee` does not return a promise

Comment: yes. but have used this.CheckLastEmployee(empId).then(x=>{isLast=x}); So in .spec file, I get error Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<boolean>' if i try spyOn(component,'CheckLastEmployee').and.returnValue(true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your test is missing async/await. Furthermore, I think in order to be able to see if your `submit` method was called, you need to spy on that method as well. Please try the following implementation to see if it solves your issue:

```js
it('Is Last Employee-submit', fakeAsync( () => {
    spyOn(component, 'CheckLastEmployee').and.resolveTo(true);
    let spy = spyOn(component, 'submit');  // Spy on submit method
    component.nextEmployee(10);
    tick(); // Try this
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // Now expect the spy to have been called if isLast is defined
}));
```

In case the above test didnt work, you can try `tick(1000)`(1000 milliseconds) or another value as well to just see if the test is failing due to a race condition or not.

### Side note:

You need to import `tick` and `fakeAsync`:

```js
import {fakeAsync, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
```

Comment: tried async/await -no change....
resolveTo(null) ->Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'boolean | undefined'. So I tried resolveTo(true)....still test case fails
I have include spy for Submit method too....missed to include in the question before..

Comment: @PriyaK Can you please include the error message when you use `resolveTo(true)`?

Comment: @PriyaK Also please share the `CheckLastEmployee` method in your question

Comment: Expected spy Submit to have been called. - error msg

Comment: @PriyaK I just found another flaw. It should be `await component.nextEmployee(10);` instead of `await nextEmployee(10);`. Could you please try this?

Comment: that another mistake on my cope-paste...its actually component.nextExmployee(10)...

Comment: @PriyaK I updated my answer one last time :)). I hope it finally works.